# Most effective way to implement TSQL function "value in a custom set of values"

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

In my project that uses Microsoft SQL server, there are a lot of instances where there are various SQL queries in form of `WHERE fieldValue IN (value1, value2, value3)`, or `fieldValue NOT IN (<set of values>)`. To manage these instances in code, the value sets are defined in a separate configuration file, where the sets are assigned a name, something like `valueSet['setName'] = [value1, value2, value3]`, and then those sets can be retrieved, where required, by name, and fed to ORM query.

I'd like now to move these set definitions to database: two tables, one for the sets (id, name, description), and another for the set contents (set id, value). And, implement a custom function that could be used in the SQL queries.

I can think of two ways to do this:

1) Scalar function

`WHERE dbo.isValueInSet(fieldValue, 'setName') = 1`

2) Table-valued function

a) `WHERE fieldValue IN (SELECT * FROM dbo.valueSet('setName'))`

or b) `INNER JOIN dbo.valueSet('setName') ON fieldValue = idFieldFromSet`, which, I assume, is no less or more effective than the (a) variant.

I am not sure maybe there is some better way. I am also concerned about performance: if I implement the scalar-value function, does that mean that it will be called for every row in the table? That feels like something awfully ineffective. In that regard, the table-value function feels like much better choice. But perhaps there is another way to implement this, that is more effective than any of the two options that I have described?

Comment: I might vote for neither option, and just writing regular SQL code using your tables for the whitelists/blacklists.

Comment: I vote against a scalar value function; these very often tend to perform poorly (especially compared to an **inline** table-value function).

Comment: " two tables, one for the sets (id, name, description), and another for the set contents (set id, value). " Meaning your set values have the same data type, or you are going to store at least some of the values in the wrong data type. A better option  might be to just have an auxiliary table for each set - and then simply join to this table. The `In` operator will probably be equivalent to a join most of the time, but it might suffer a performance hit if the set is large.

Answer (score 0):

Do not do scalar.

Do not do a table function.  The optimiser assumes 1 row returned, which is rarely the case and can cause the occasional inappropriate query plans.

I would continue what you are doing or embed the full query, removing the function:

```
WHERE fieldValue IN (SELECT VAL FROM VALUE_TABLE where VAL_SET_NAME='setName')
```

Comment: Does the optimizer assume 1 row also for inline table-valued functions?

Comment: As far as I know it still does.  Give it a go and check the query plan.  Some evidence that 100 is also a default value depending on the version of SQL Server. https://www.sqlshack.com/improvements-of-scalar-user-defined-function-performance-in-sql-server-2019/